# Show all sides of a solidworks part in a solidworks drawing

Tags: solidworks, drawings

I'm new to solidworks, and I built my part and would like to put it into a drawing. Its a small square box-like base with one side of the base having holes in it. When I put my parts into the drawing, it shows 2 sides of the base, a bottom view, and an isometric view, but it never shows the side/plane with the holes on it. My question is this, how do I have a solidworks drawing show a different plane or side of the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Projected View" button to add another view, by selecting an existing view. You should bear in mind, however, that you should avoid adding unnecessary views if you can fully define the geometry of the object with only a few. I can't comment on this without an image of your object, however.

[image: Projected View Button]